# Create dynamic list in Google Sheets using based upon input

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I am facing problem to add dynamic data in Google Sheets

[image: Screenshot]

If I enter 3 in B1 it should create list 3 times as in the screenshot. The data will come from a range.

I can easily do it using GAS but I am looking to have a more reliable solution using in-built Google sheet functions.

Comment: what do you mean by "on left hand side" ? only column D? or all columns (B, C, D)?

Comment: Yes,all columns (B,C,D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(
 "♠Laptop♦Apple♦2♠Phone♦Windows♦1♠Headphones♦Boss♦5♠♦ ♦ ♦", B1), 
 "♠")), "♦"))
```

[image]

Comment: sure. so you have a string of values `"♠Laptop♦Apple♦2♠Phone♦Windows♦1♠Headphones♦Boss♦5♠♦ ♦ ♦"` joined with `♦` and `♠`. these symbols are like divisors so we could split the string into rows (with `♠`) and then into columns (with `♦`). eg we repeat string 4times (B1) with `REPT`, then `SPLIT` by rows on `♠` (this will split it into columns so we use `TRANSPOSE` to fix it), then we `SPLIT` those rows on `♦` into columns, and we outputting array/range so we use `ARRAYFORMULA`. and yes, you can use any unique symbols you wish - ♂♀♪♫♥♣•◘↨×....

Comment: Good,Thank you so much!
One more thing, from where I can learn more on all functions like =rept() with practical examples.

Comment: check here maybe: https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en&ref_topic=9054531